# iisnode get remoteAddress

Tags: socket.io, iisnode, sticky-session

Trying to get iisnode and socket.io to work (has been working fine on linux). I'm using Sticky session to be able to use multiple processors.

Now when running thru iisnode I'm having issues getting the remote ip from the client.

Looks like connection.headers is empty. What am I missing?

```
var server = net.createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true }, function (connection) {

    // Incoming request processing

    // We received a connection and need to pass it to the appropriate
    // worker. Get the worker for this connection's source IP and pass
    // it the connection.
    var remote = connection.remoteAddress; // this returns undefined
    var local = connection.localAddress; // this returns undefined 
    var ip = (remote + local).match(/[0-9]+/g)[0].replace(/,/g, '');
    var wIndex = ip % num_processes;

    var worker = workers[wIndex];

    console.log("Message to work "+ worker+", remote: "+ remote+ ", local: "+ local+", ip: "+ ip +", index: "+ wIndex);
    worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);

});
```

Update:
When using pause { pauseOnConnect: true } you cannot access the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is your issue but with IISNode, you need to explicitly tell it that you're going to use Socket.io in the Web.config.

You do this in two places within your Web.config:

**Inside the `<handlers>` element**

```
<handlers>
  <!-- Change the path attribute to your main file-->
  <add name="iisnode-socket.io" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>
```

**Add an additional URL Re-Write rule for Socket.io**

```
<rule name="SocketIO" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
  <match url="socket.io.+" />

  <!-- Change the url attribute to your main file-->
  <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
</rule>
```